# Spring :Accessing Property Place holder values through Environment

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Can I access properties declared in `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` through environment variable.I understand it cant be accessed through `environment.getProperty(propName)`. But is there anyway to perform environment.addPropertySource using xml.As I dont want to use `@Configuration` annotation. I'm using Spring 4.

Comment: No there isn't, nor should you be using `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` but the `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`, which is automatically done when using `<context:property-placeholder />`. But there is no way of adding sources through XML only `@Configuration` with `@PropertySource` or by using an `ApplicationContextInitializer` and adding them through code. What is wrong with a `@Configuration` class?

Comment: If i use <code>@Configuration</code> I have to use @propertySource as well and I dont want to have the name of properties file in the java class.if there is a way out to do the same via xml ,then please tell me the same.

Comment: What is the difference in having it in a Java configuration or XML configuration? And as mentioned there isn't a way to do it in XML.